# Group by in query Google Sheet select different columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Want to get the results described on the screenshot. How can I achieve it.

[image]

QUERY:

```
=QUERY(A2:F12,"SELECT A, MAX(B), MIN(B) group by A label A 'G V1', MAX(B) 'LAST V2', MIN(B) 'FIRST V2'")
```

Want to get First & last V5 value in terms of max and min dates in V2 (see K2, L2 desired results), I could get the last and first dates now I want their V5 corresponding.

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @marikamitsos Find the shared sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ykOeQQRDxRbJc-eyb8KSrAsJV2Yd4EYyrHHbA2bOS64/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @marikamitsos, any feedback or hint? thank you

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research regarding the result you are looking for as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I worthy to note that the result you are looking could not be achieved by using a single QUERY function, in other words, you should use another formula or use a single but complex formula. If the values in B are unique you could use them as "keys" and use VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH or other similar lookup soluctions.

Comment: Actually, i am not expert in google sheets, that's why asked the Q to unblock me in another different topic. but it seems that I should learn it anyway. Appreciate a quick solution if possible otherwise i should look for a course.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work for the entire end goal, but, based on the observation that every column is the result of a query returning one row, is it possible that you may be able to have one simple query per column, each returning one row.  For example:
[image]

The formula for columns:

- `E1`: `=query(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8, "select max(A) group by A")`
- `F1`: `=query(Sheet1!$A$2:$B$8, "select max(B) group by A")`
- `G1`: `=query(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$8, "select min(B) group by A")`
- `H1`: `=query(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$8, "select max(C) group by A")`
- `I1`: `=query(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$8, "select min(C) group by A")`

Notes:

- google sheets wants to stick in the "max" and "min" title & it's a pain to remove it
- you can remove the `Sheet1`, that's just there in case the data is on a different sheet (tab). Of course change it or remove it (and the trailing `!`) if the sheet isn't called `Sheet1`.
- if it's easier to include the entire range of the whole table, it'll still work, but might impact performance(?), e.g., you can use `$A$2:$C$8` in each query.

Answer (score 0):

You can even have your results in a single long formula in cell `H1`

```
={QUERY({A2:F},"SELECT Col1, MAX(Col2), MIN(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'G V1', MAX(Col2) 'LAST V2', MIN(Col2) 'FIRST V2' "), 
   QUERY({"LAST V5", "FIRST V5";IFERROR(ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(QUERY({A2:F},"SELECT MAX(Col2), MIN(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label MAX(Col2) 'LAST V2', MIN(Col2) 'FIRST V2' "),B2:F,{4,4},0)))})}
```

*(I would personally go against it since [you mention](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142825/group-by-in-query-google-sheet-select-different-columns#comment130447_142825): "Actually, i am not expert in google sheets...")*

---

Please use the following formula in cell `K2`

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(I2:J,B2:E,{4,4},0)))
```

[image]

In the formula we used open ranges. That means that the ranges are in the form `I2:I`, `B2:E` etc.

The same way you can extend your original query formula to the open range `A2:F`

```
=QUERY(A2:F,"SELECT A, MAX(B), MIN(B) where A is not null group by A label A 'G V1', MAX(B) 'LAST V2', MIN(B) 'FIRST V2'")
```

Notice that we added the `where` clause `where A is not null` to omit empty cells.

Functions used:

- **[`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)**
- **[`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)**
- **[`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)**
- **[`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)**

Comment: Sorry for the [late answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142825/group-by-in-query-google-sheet-select-different-columns#comment130397_142825). Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: It would be nice if you let us know what and if worked for you :)